# how to get session on supabase Oauth

Tags: next.js, oauth, supabase, supabase-js

I have an issue on this supabase authentication i tried to login with google account

```
const supabase = createClientComponentClient()
      const handleGoogle = async () => {
         const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
           provider: 'google',
           options: {
             redirectTo: 'http://localhost:3000/protected'
          }
         })
        if (error) {
           console.log(error)
        }
      }
```

here i have my handleGoogle login function i config the options to redirect to my protected page then on my protected page i want to check if there's session or not

```
const supabase = createServerComponentClient({ cookies })
      const { data: { session } } = await supabase.auth.getSession()
       if (!session) {
        redirect('/')
       }
```

even though i have login first its always redirect to the root page can some one help me

what did i do wrong can someone help me to figure out on this auth

Comment: Are you using the PKCE flow? You can follow the guide here to make sure you are using it properly. 
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/oauth-with-pkce-flow-for-ssr